How to Annotate an Architectural Diagram of a Fort with Geo-Coordinates for Mapping Purposes?
I have an image that represents the architectural diagram of a fort. I want to annotate this diagram with geo-coordinates so I can pinpoint my current location over the image.

Considerations:

It's uncertain if this diagram is true to size. This means it is only a visual representation of the actual fort, and dimensions in this map cannot be scaled to match the dimensions of the actual fort.
The diagram is tilted at a certain angle and does not represent an exact topographic view (view from above) of the fort. Therefore, I'm not sure how to georeference this image and use it as a layer on mapping services like Google Maps, OpenStreetMap, or Leaflet.

As a coder, I am thinking about placing coordinates (x, y) over certain pixels of this image. This would create a virtual grid over the image, allowing me to cross-reference my location in the grid.
Could anyone suggest any other solutions or systems I might be unaware of?
